# dd "direct" versus "nocache"

Tags: dd, io, cache

According to the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dd-invocation.html) for `dd`, there are two options that can cause I/O to bypass the filesystem cache: `direct` and `nocache`. When using these flags to, for example, copy files or copy raw data to/from block devices, what are the differences between these two flags?

Let's say I want to copy one file from A to B using just `dd` (no real reason, just an experiment), in a way that `dd` will...

1. ...read one full block from the input file, without putting it in the read cache, and then...
2. ...write that data to the destination as soon as a full block is read, without putting it in the write cache.

What do these flags do differently for this example scenario? What would be the proper invocation of `dd` for this task?

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer: I can't say definitively, but this is my best guess.**

## No Cache:

*Read* unaligned input directly from the device.

## Direct I/O:

Read *and* write aligned data without using either the OS's internal buffers *or* L* caching.

---

In summation, if you wanted to avoid OS/L* caching altogether just go with the `direct` I/O option.  If it's only read caching you're trying to avoid, `nocache` should suffice.

Comment: It’s a pretty good guess. `direct` opens files with `O_DIRECT`, which on Linux tries to minimise the use of caches, and reads and writes directly to and from the userspace buffers. `nocache` uses `posix_fadvise` to tell the kernel that the caches can be dropped, *after* reads; so caches are used, but hopefully for a short while only.